# Update price frontend based on custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, custom-options

I need to change the frontend price of a product when two custom options dropdowns are selected. I have found some code in this question, but where do I put the files?
[change price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60512/use-magento-opconfig-reloadprice-with-jquery-and-custom-options)

**UPDATE1:**

added below codeto the options file and nothing happens when I adjust the quantity ?

```
$('#qty').keyup(function(){
alert('test');
});
```

**UPDATE2**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 $('#qty').keyup(function(){
    alert('test');
    });
```

but now report 'Function expected'

**UPDATE 3**
I have the test code working now, Thanks. The real code doesnt work as expected, I want to update the price on the product page. This should equal the value of the dropdown multiplied x 4. Currently the code updates the price by adding 50 to it.

```
jQuery('#select_3').removeAttr('onchange').change(function(){
price=50;
optionsPrice.chagePrice('opConfig',price);
optionsPrice.reload();
```

Comment: You can put the javascript in template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

Comment: doesnt appear to work, see updated answer pls.

Comment: Beware for this is clearly jQuery, you should not use "$" which is reserved to prototype. Consider https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Do you have any error/warning in javascript console?

Comment: yes error occured so changed code, now a new error 'Function expected'

Comment: Hi, no error now but alert box does not display

Comment: No, use jQuery('#qty').keyup(function(){ alert('test'); });

Comment: Thanks I have test code working now, I've tried the proper code now but doesnt work as expected. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code, I sppose you meant

```
jQuery('#select_3').removeAttr('onchange').change(function(){
    var price=50; //add var declaration
    optionsPrice.changePrice('opConfig',price);
    optionsPrice.reload();
}); //close the change binding
```

But where does optionsPrice come from? Pay a closer attention to the answers, I won't explain them here: your topic would be marked as 'duplicate' and you should ask for explanations on the original topic.

Comment: as i have under 50 reputation I cant add comment to orginal answer so grateful for support. 
optionsPrice came from the previous answer, I thought it was a class ?? I've now prefixed  var infront of  price=50 but still get summation of 50+price.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60531/7773 -> if you want to update the price, that should not be in javascript (clientside) but in php (serverside)

Comment: Dont I need to do client side in addition to server side to give the user an immediate result?

Comment: Then you might consider ajax call, something like this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15579192/2375207

Comment: There it is, custom option price in the cart http://stackoverflow.com/a/23099871/2375207

Comment: I've added custom options on the product and left prices blank. If I add the code in link you provided will it calculate cost on frontend and backend?

Comment: you are going offtopic, start a new one or ask on another topic for more info.